# Intensity of a light beam at material transition

Tags: optics, refraction

The definition of the intensity of light is given as
$$I=0.5\varepsilon_0n_0\vert E\vert^2$$
Now, when transitioning from one material with $n_1=1$ to another one with $n_2=2$ at a normal incident angle, I will have a reflection coefficient of
$$r=\left\vert\frac{n_1 - n_2}{n_1 + n_2}\right\vert^2\approx0.11$$
which means that
$$I_2=0.89I_1$$
and
$$\begin{split}\vert E_2\vert^2&=\frac{0.89I_1}{2\cdot\varepsilon_0n_2}\\
&=\frac{0.89}{2\cdot\varepsilon_0n_2}\frac{\varepsilon_0n_1\vert E_1\vert^2}{2}\\
&=0.445\vert E_1\vert^2\end{split}$$
If I interpret that correctly, that means that I will have a non-continuous transition between the magnitude of the electrical fields at the border of the material. Is that correct?

Comment: You are only looking at mod-square of the fields. Do not forget that the field is a complex entity with amplitude and phase. At the interface the description results in an amplitude and phase change, but the complex E-field must be of course continuous...

Comment: A minor comment. I don't know which conventions are you using, but in SI units the intensity of a plane wave should be $0.5\sqrt{\frac{\varepsilon_0}{\mu_0}}n|E|^2$. This doesn't affect the results, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transmitted wave into the second material will have a magnitude of $|E_2|^2=0.445|E_1|^2$ as you say (actually is $|E_2|^2=\displaystyle\frac{4}{9}|E_1|^2$ if you do the calculations without losing decimals). Therefore $|E_2|=\displaystyle\frac{2}{3}|E_1|$.

In the first material, however, you also have to take into account the reflected wave, which will have a magnitude of

$$|E_{reflected}|=\left|\frac{n_1-n_2}{n_1+n_2}\right||E_1|=\frac{1}{3}|E_1|.$$

This reflected wave has a phase shift by $\pi$, because the reflected wave always has a phase shift when light passes from an optically thinner medium to an optically thicker one ($n_1<n_2$). Hence the continuity of the parallel component of $E$ to the interface is fullfilled
$$|E_{incident}|-|E_{reflected}|=|E_{transmitted}|$$
or with your notation
$$|E_1|-|E_{reflected}|=|E_2|$$
$$|E_1|-\frac{1}{3}|E_1|=\frac{2}{3}|E_1|$$
where the minus sign accounts for the phase shift.